# How to restore the inking strokes after suspend and shutdown in winRT?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

Is there is a need to restore the painting while app terminating during inking in winRT? How can I achieve that?

Any help will really appreciated 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's inking? You have a drawing app with a canvas on it where a user can draw stuff?

Comment: @igrali yes.It's drawing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which scenario you are used to paint.

if you are use MS InkManager,then you can use SaveAsync() API to save the stream when closing the app, and LoadAsync() API to Load the stream to paint when restart the app.

if you are just use shape to paint, you can save the points to local when closing and rebuild the lines using these points when restart the app.

Comment: any chance of a code sample of this?  my head spins when i try to figure out the different stream formats etc.  I'm trying to figure out how to make an InputStream from a standard stream

Comment: Buzzrick have you figured out a way to do this? I'm also messing with the streams but can't quite get it right. Always gives a COMException